# How do I check if a list with a range of items exists in another list

Tags: python

Trying to figure out how to check if 1 of any number of lists is in a sublist - without doing it manually.

The lists I'm checking for look like this:

[10, ANY VALUE, ANY VALUE]

The values should be between 0 - 120. So some of the values can be.

```
[10, 1, 4]
[10, 1, 2]
[10, 0, 0]
```

etc...

Here is an example of the list I want to find it in:

`items = [[3, 5, 0], [10, 1, 0], [10, 127, 127], [22, 4, 0], [22, 125, 127]]`

So this would pull out `[10, 1, 0]`

Ideally it needs to work with an if in statement which looks like this:

```
if [10, 127, 127] in items and [10, ANY, ANY] in items:
    # do something
```

Comment: `[10, 127, 127]` also matches `[10, ANY, ANY]`, so what is the point of looking for both?

Comment: Ah yeah it needs to be ANY other value between 0 - 120. So that excludes 127 127. It's basically if they exist together. But your answer below is helpful, I can just add the x[1] < 120 and x[2] < 120 to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `any()` function:

```
if [10, 127, 127] in items and any(len(x) == 3 and x[0] == 10 for x in items):
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured the any() function would have the answer but couldn't get my head around the logic.

Comment: This logic would give `True` if `[10, 127, 127]` was the only item in the list--it finds it twice. Not sure if that's what OP wants.